# Calling function from inside cur.execute(...)

Tags: sql, psycopg2

Inside my SQL tool, I have a query which calls a function:

```
UPDATE test
SET data = myfunction(data)
WHERE my_id = 'test';
```

which runs fine.

But when I run this inside cursor.execute() using psycopg2, I get an UndefinedFunction error. I can see documentation on how to a stored procedure using cursor.callproc(), but how do I call it from inside a query, using execute()?

Thanks!

Comment: I would check what schema you created `myfunction`  under since the schema in executing queries defaults to the `search_path` which defaults to `public`. If your function is stored in a schema other than the default you can call it with the syntax of `"my_schema".myfunction(data)`